# After Effects: How to do Organic Contraction effect

Tags: video, after-effects, effects

I've seen this effect in a lot of videos, you can take a look here:
[video link](https://i.imgur.com/ElEDOTN.mp4)

Which key word identifies this contraction movement effect? Or how can we do that?

Comment: "pulsing" may be a better search term for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a 3D deformation happening here, along with an optical glow on the bass beats.

I would guess this was made in After Effects, using the plugins [Trapcode Form](https://www.maxon.net/en/red-giant-complete/trapcode-suite/form) or possibly [Plexus](https://aescripts.com/plexus/) with [Sound Keys](https://www.maxon.net/en/red-giant-complete/trapcode-suite/sound-keys) applied to a deformer using the bass in the music.  Then an [Optical Glow](https://www.maxon.net/en/red-giant-complete/vfx-suite/optical-glow) added which gets more intense using the same keyframes from the bass.